# Phoenix - Access Erlang dependency

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using **Phoenix** (v1.2.1) to build a **REST API**, but I know very little about **Elixir** and pretty much zero about **Erlang**.

As part of the `create` action on one of my controllers, `group_controller.ex`, I need to query an external source to generate some data.  The logic for producing this query is in an Erlang dependency that has been added to my `mix.exs` deps and successfully installed in the `deps` directory... so that is all good.

However, I haven't the slightest idea how to import the module or access its functionality in my controller (or anywhere in my app, for that matter).  Can I even use an Erlang dependency out of the box in a Phoenix app, or does it need to be transpiled to Elixir?

If I were writing this in ES6, I would write something like

```
import {FunctionA, FunctionB} from 'module'
```

easy as pie... how can I accomplish that in Phoenix when the dependency is written in Erlang?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `:module.functionA(args)` ? Post details of the module/method you want to use, so we can better answer you question.

Comment: @Sheharyar Wow, thank you!  I didn't realize that it would be that easy - this works perfectly. Can you rephrase that as an answer and submit below so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Calling Methods on Erlang Modules

Erlang modules are accessible as `atoms` of their module names in elixir, and you can call their methods like any other Modules:

```
:module.function(arguments)
```

---

**For Example:**

To call the `uniform/0` method of the Erlang `random` module, you can do this:

```
:random.uniform
```

Comment: Thanks you! This makes sense, just didn't know the syntax.